# Stacking of histograms plotly express

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have a dataframe which consists of day, hour and total_clicks. I need to plot a histogram for all the days stacked together. Below is my dataframe i.e; **result_df**

```
    day hour total_clicks
0   1   0   1.0
1   1   1   12.0
2   1   2   13.0
3   1   3   1.0
4   1   4   0.0
... ... ... ...
715 30  19  0.0
716 30  20  0.0
717 30  21  4.0
718 30  22  0.0
719 30  23  5.0
```

I wrote a for loop where it is giving separate plots

```
for i in range(min_day, max_day+1):
    title = 'sep ' + str(i)
    df = result_df[result_df['day']==i]
    fig = px.histogram(df, x="hour", y="total_clicks", marginal="rug",nbins=24,
                   hover_data=df.columns,title=title)
    fig.show()
```

but I need all the graphs stacked together in a single plot so that we can see the total clicks for all the days in a single plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the total by day, you can use `color='day'`. Does this fit the intent of your question?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np

date_rng = pd.date_range('2020-09-01 00:00:00', '2020-09-30 23:00:00', freq='1H')
value = np.random.randint(0,50, size=720)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.to_datetime(date_rng), 'total_clicks':value})
df['day'] = df['date'].dt.day
df['hour'] = df['date'].dt.hour
result_df = df.copy()
fig = px.histogram(df, x="hour", y="total_clicks", color='day', marginal="rug", nbins=24,
           hover_data=df.columns, title='Sep')
fig.show()
```

[image]